# Programmatically get running application bundles in OS X

Tags: c, macos, go

I'm trying to get a list of all running Application Bundles. GUI applications that the user has started, like the Dock is showing, or Activity Monitor (it shows an icon next to certain processes). I found that I could use `sysctl()` with `KERN_PROC_ALL` to get a list of all running processes, but that won't tell me which application bundle they are from. Applications like Minecraft just show up as `java` and that's not very useful.

I did find that the process group name in activity monitor shows roughly what I want to know:
[image: Activity Monitor Showing Minecraft Launcher Running]
<sub>(source: [gdries.nl](http://gdries.nl/activmon.png))</sub>

The implementation language is not important. Currently working in C and go, but if some other environment turns out to be required that's not a problem. All I want to do is detect which applications the user has running so I can log the time that each has been used. (Parental Controls does something similar but logs it in plist files that I can't parse)

Comment: download the code for the 'ps' utility and use what you need of that.

Comment: 'ps' only knows about processes and has no idea what application bundle a process is from or even that there is such a thing as an application bundle. It gives me the same information I can already get with `sysctl`, `KERN_PROC_ALL` and `KERN_PROCARGS` (although the latter's return format is arcane and undocumented).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a way to do it using Swift and Cocoa APIs. Presumably, this should also be possible using plain C, but this is good enough for my application.

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

// Get all running applications
let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared
let applications = workspace.runningApplications

for app in applications {
    print(app)
}
```

`app` is an `NSApplication` object, and that has a bundle identifier, which is what I wanted to know.

Comment: In Swift 4 `NSWorkspace.shared` instead of `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()` worked for me.