# OSX/Swift List Currently Running Processes

Tags: macos

I'm new to programming with swift and osx, and I've seen a variety of apps that allow users to view app processes that are consuming a lot of memory on macs. I was wondering if there is a way in swift that we could obtain and list currently running apps. I'm trying to figure this out so that I can detect when an app of interest opens, so that the app can do something. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029633/how-do-you-access-command-line-arguments-in-swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically get running application bundles in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954721/programmatically-get-running-application-bundles-in-os-x)