# How to get the status of any specified process and service on Mac from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos, process

I need to get the status of any service and process to know if it is running or not with Swift or Objective C.

I am working on a MacOS application. I need to get the status of any service and process to know if it is running or not, I am not an experienced developer with Swift or Objective C. I built a Windows application that does that, but I don't know how to do it in these languages, and I need it.

I read and I think I can do it with the Process class in swift but I still can't.

If someone has been used in this class or knows another way to solve it, I would appreciate it

Comment: Look at this [SO programmatically-get-running-application-bundles-in-os-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954721/programmatically-get-running-application-bundles-in-os-x)

Comment: Indeed, the above link points to how to retrieve *some* running applications in user land, but if you require all processes running or not, including privileged helpers, then that's far more complicated than that, because that requires root access and super-user privileges.